# How can I dump those if's?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in programming and I need some help. Is there any other option to write the *get_the_thing* function? In my opinion there is no need to use so much if's.

```
class SomeClass():

    def __init__(self, things): 
        self._1 = things[0]
        self._2 = things[1]
        self._3 = things[2]
        self._4 = things[3]

    def get_the_thing(self, bok):

        self.bok = int(bok)
        if bok == 1:
            return (self._1)
        if bok == 2:
            return (self._2)
        if bok == 3:
            return (self._3)
        if bok == 4:
            return (self._4)
```

Comment: Why are you saving content of 'things' in separate variables? You can easily use a list..

Comment: Easy - use a map/dictionary.

Comment: Lol, people in stackoverflow are really mean. I mean, they are downvoting this question but not telling why... Like when your parents ground you, and for asking 'why am I being grounded?' the grounding period gets extended.
PS: I didn't downvote

Comment: Agreed (didn't downvote), but a lot of questions from new users get downvoted, just hang in there :)

Comment: Are you looking to dynamically create instance attributes based on how many items are in `things`?

Comment: Don't take it personally.  You can't live on the Internet or SO with such a thin skin.

Comment: @BAH: Questions don't get downvoted because they are from new users. Questions get downvoted because they are not particularly useful additions to the repository, due to obviousness or lack of research. Though this one seems difficult to downvote.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet agreed, I guess my statement came out somewhat wrong. I was talking more along the lines of many new users asking questions specific to their use case, and yes, those might have obvious solutions making the question seem useless, but if were a beginner I wouldn't know what else to ask. It would help if the downvoters explained their downvotes, but unfortunately that's not always the case.

Comment: @BAH: We're encouraged not to explain downvotes, because it leads to revenge downvoting and strops. Can't have it both ways, I suppose.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet ah I see, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the things as they are.

```
class SomeClass():
    def __init__(self, things): 
        self._things = things

    def get_the_thing(self, bok):
        return self._things[bok - 1]
```

Comment: If `bok`s are integers you can just say use a `list` and keep this answer

Comment: But, he probably will need to decrease 'bok' by 1, since the 'things' is a list, and to get it, he is using 'bok' value 1-4 instead of 0-3.

Comment: Oh, I did it again! Anyway it will work with lists as well.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was thinking about.

Comment: Just store the things as they are? Goyo did not take any risk at all by mentioning 'list' or 'dict' :P :P :P This is hilarious :P

Comment: hahah, you might wanna cast bok into an int - he's doing it in the original post, but I'm not sure if he's aware that that's only required if bok is a string.

Comment: I acknowledge it's really a bad answer. I succumbed to the temptation to guess and then I was lazy and did not test. But it seems like the OP found it useful so I will leave it.

Comment: Yes, please do not make it all technical. Answers like this are good. Both helpful and fun to read. :D :D